# How do I reveal a MS Graph (search result) driveItem File's path (folder)?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, microsoft-graph-api

I have following (kotlin/java based) query in MSGraph

```
var driveItemSearchCollectionRequestBuilder =
    safeGraphServiceClient
        .sites(SHAREPOINT_SITE_ID)
        .drive()
        .root()
        .search("¤A=118628")

do{

    driveItemSearchCollectionPage = driveItemSearchCollectionRequestBuilder?.buildRequest()?.get()?:break

    driveItemSearchCollectionPage.currentPage.map {driveItem->
        driveItem?.let{ safeDriveItem ->
           
           //Here I need to find my `safeDriveItem`'s (which is a file) path (where the file is stored)... (or folder)
           //`safeDriveItem.folder` is null... (since this is a file)
        }
    }
    driveItemSearchCollectionRequestBuilder = driveItemCollectionPage.nextPage

}while(driveItemSearchCollectionRequestBuilder!=null)
```

which results in a set (page) of driveItems. This search can find the file in any folder in my sharepoint tree. Where (or how) can I find the drivItem file's folder (i.e. '\MyFolder\Level1\Level2\Level3')? (The folder item is `null` for driveItem here, and I haven't found any value which contains it). Or do I need to do som "clever" backtracking?

Comment: When ever you search using the above code, as you said you will be getting the driveItems. Pick the id of the driveItem which you want the Folder path for and then call `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{siteid}/drive/Items/{driveItemid}` which will pull the whole drive item object which has a `parentReferrence` object which internally have path property in it.

Comment: Did it work for you?

Comment: Actually, I am just going to test it now... give me some coffe cups...

Comment: Thanx, tested it, and I can pull the path from that secondary query. Why doesn't MGraph populate that value in my primary search request, or do I need to add some parameter in the search ?

I will answer my Q with your suggestion above and quute is as solved.

Comment: I will add the answer with your followup question.Please accept it :)-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When ever you search using the above code, as you said you will be getting the driveItems. Pick the id of the driveItem which you want the Folder path for and then call

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{siteid}/drive/Items/{driveItemid}`

which will pull the whole drive item object which has a parentReferrence object which internally have path property in it.

Sharepoint has two different data sources where search will pull the data by indexing from one source and few properties may not showup. So pulling an object directly gives you all the properties.

Answer (score 0):

@Shiva found a solution, and I can now query the path for my file like this:

```
var driveItemSearchCollectionRequestBuilder =
    safeGraphServiceClient
        .sites(SHAREPOINT_SITE_ID)
        .drive()
        .root()
        .search("¤A=118628")

do{

    driveItemSearchCollectionPage = driveItemSearchCollectionRequestBuilder?.buildRequest()?.get()?:break

    driveItemSearchCollectionPage.currentPage.map {driveItem->
        driveItem?.let{ safeDriveItem ->

           val pathItem =  safeGraphServiceClient
               .sites(SHAREPOINT_SITE_ID)
               .drive()
               .items(safeDriveItem.id)
               .buildRequest()
               .get()

           val path = pathItem.parentReference.path 

           galleryItems.add(path, driveItem.name) //My functiomn adds now path and file to db 

        }
    }
    driveItemSearchCollectionRequestBuilder = driveItemCollectionPage.nextPage

}while(driveItemSearchCollectionRequestBuilder!=null)
```

I hope in future the `driveItem.parentReference.path` could be populated so we can avoid a secondary call to Graph, or there is some switch to set on the search phrase to disclose the path (communication cost perspective).